# How to pivot_longer a set of multiple columns? and How to go back from that long format to original wide?

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

If I have the following data:

```
D = tibble::tribble(
  ~firm, ~ind, ~var1_1, ~var1_2, ~op2_1, ~op2_2,
  "A",     1,     10,     11,     11,     12,
  "A",     2,     12,     13,     13,     14,
  "B",     1,     14,     15,     15,     16,
  "B",     2,     16,     17,     17,     18,
  "C",     1,     18,     19,     19,     20,
  "C",     2,     20,     21,     21,     22,
)
```

How can I `pivot_longer()` var1 and var2 having "_*" as year indicator?

I mean, I would like have something like this:

```
D %>%
  pivot_longer(var1_1:op2_2,
  names_to = c(".value", "year"),
  names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)",
  values_to = c("var1, var2")
  )
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   firm    ind year   var1  op2
   <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A         1 1        10    11
 2 A         1 2        11    12
 3 A         2 1        12    13
 4 A         2 2        13    14
 5 B         1 1        14    15
 6 B         1 2        15    16
 7 B         2 1        16    17
 8 B         2 2        17    18
 9 C         1 1        18    19
10 C         1 2        19    20
11 C         2 1        20    21
12 C         2 2        21    22
```

I'm achieving the desired result using the code above. However in my real case I'm dealing with more than 30 variables and 10 years. Then, using `values_to` isn't practical and clean. I'd like the code read first part of variable name as the desired new variable name. Since initially all columns to be pivoted are structured like **"varname_year"**.

> Besides, once I get the new data format into long, I might need to go back to wide-format keeping the initial data structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use one of the `select_helpers`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
Dlong <- D %>%
          pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('var'), 
             names_to = c(".value", "year"), names_sep = "_")
```

---

From the 'long' format, change to 'wide' with `pivot_wider`

```
Dlong %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = ind, values_from = str_c("var", 1:2))
```

Comment: What if all columns starts with a different name?

Comment: @Cristhian  Many options are there, either `matches` or just use a numeric index

Comment: Upvote because you are awesome.